# gtm.js not firing on Google Tag Manager implementation

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to setup GA4 pageviews by configurating on Google Tag Manager. I've done this multiple times for multiple websites and I've never come across this problem before. I am not a technical expert, but I do have some technical knowledge. I just don't understand what exactly is going wrong..

So, the problem...
Basically I have a clean, fresh made container and the GTM codes are properly implemented according to Google Guidelines. The **head** code is placed at the start of the **head** opening tag and the **body** code is placed directly after the **body** opening tag.

For some reason my container just isn't loading. These are all datalayers that are being pushed:
[image]

My pageview requires ***event = gtm.js*** which is being pushed on "Container loaded"..

So the first problem is that the "container loaded" does not appear. I have no idea why, but what I found out is when I try to look in dev. console on the GTM debug page, i get a 403 error:
[image]

Note, this dev console error does not show in the regular non-test version, only in debug mode. On the website all JS files are status 200.

I am stuck with this one and I just can't seem to figure it out. If someone can give any leads or advise on how to proceed it will be greatly appreciated. Feel free to ask additional information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you publish your container at least once? It's not enough to create a container, you also need to publish it...

Comment: Yes, the container is published.

Comment: Are you using an ad blocker, content blocker, or some other privacy feature? Have you tried it in other browsers?

Comment: @ZoeEdwards I haven't tried it in another browser, but other GTM containers I control are working properly. Therefore I ruled my browser completely out.

Comment: you're not trying to deploy a server-side container on web, are you?